# Is this a good way to break out of the while loop if there is not substring?

Tags: c++, string

I'm working on this small code. It is giving the right output but I think the loop that I have on it could be improved.

> Question 1: Given a string `A` consisting of `n` characters, and a string `B` consisting of `m` characters, write a function that will return the number of times `A` must be stated such that `B` is a substring of the repeated `A`. If `B` can never be a substring, return `-1`.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> A = "abcd"
> B = "cdabcdab"
> ```
>
> The function should return 3 because after stating `A` 3 times, getting `"abcdabcdabcd"`, `B` is now a substring of `A`.
>
> You can assume that `n` and `m` are integers in the range `[1, 1000]`.

This is my code:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <istream>

using namespace std;
int findthestring(string A, string B)
{
    string original = B;
    int times = 1 ;
    if (B.find(A) != string::npos)
    {
        cout << "String Found\n";
        times =1;

    }
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < (10 * A.length());i++)
    {
        cout << "String not Found\n";
        B = B + original;
        times = times + 1;
        if (times>10)
        {
            return -1;
            break;
        }
    }

    return times;   
}

int main()
{
    int times = findthestring("cdabcdab","abcd");
    cout << "Number of Times: " << times;
    return 0;
}
```

On this code, I have the loop run for 10 times, if there is no sub string, then the loop breaks out and returns 1.

Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: First check if `A` exists in `B`.  That will let you know if it is possible.  Then you can use that position to calculate how many times `A` would need to appear.

Comment: Thank you ! I did that and I changed the for loop to a while loop                   
    while (B.find(A) == string::npos)
Now I'm not sure how to break out of it if there is no sub string.

Comment: `break` in the line after `return -1`? What do you expect that to do? You should set a higher warning level when compiling and check the compiler warnings.

Comment: Isn't your question better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: "*It is giving the right output but I think the loop that I have on it could be improved*" - such questions do indeed belong on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), not on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You could use recursively the method `string::find(const std::string& str, size_t pos = 0)` while its returned value would be equal to `std::string::npos`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int findthestring(const std::string& substr, const std::string& str)
{
    size_t times = 1;
    std::string temp(substr);
    while (temp.find(str) == std::string::npos) { // while not found
        times++;
        if (times > 10) {
            return -1;
        }
        temp += substr; // concatenate string
    }
    return times;
}

int main()
{
    int times = findthestring("abcd", "cdabc");
    std::cout << "Number of Times: " << times;
    return 0;
}
```